# Is the minimal uncountable set $S_{\Omega}$ used outside of general topology?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

In asking this question, I do not wish to sound imperious or presumptuous about the uses of general topology. I read about the minimal well-ordered uncountable set $S_{\Omega}$ in Munkre's topology, which I was self-studying as a prerequisite to Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. Is $S_{\Omega}$ used outside of general topology? Does it ever make an appearance in Algebraic topology or differential geometry for that matter? Please correct me if this next presentiment is unjustified, but I cannot help but feel that $S_{\Omega}$ is rather artificial, existing solely for the purpose of generating counterexamples and paradoxes. I tried searching for a definition of the elements of $S_{\Omega}$ on the internet and was told that no such statement existed. Is that true? How can I properly develop an intuition for object, if the its constituents are not rigorously defined? If I were to keep my examination of this topic to a minimum, would I regret my decision in Algebraic topology or other courses?

For reference, $S_{\Omega}$ is defined to be *uncountable* so that any section $S_{a} = \{s \in S_{\Omega} : s < a\}$ is countable. $S_{\Omega}$ is also taken to be well ordered.

Comment: This question seems (perhaps my impression is wrong, though) to rest on the mistaken assumption that $S_{\Omega}$ is "something from general topology" to begin with. It is not. Instead, $S_{\Omega}$ is something from the theory of ordinal numbers, which is studied in set theory. The use of these ordinal numbers is within set theory. In general topology, they only appear as curious examples. In algebraic topology, they do not appear.

Comment: It is also sometimes used in measure theory to construct interesting sets (counterexamples), mostly in connection with the continuum hypothesis.